# Input stays focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with an Input. When I complete it and when press on a button, the .click function on this button didn't work, and the input stay focused.

Can you please explain to me how this can be?

```
<div style="border-width: 2px;  background-color: #34495e; border-style: solid; position: fixed; padding: 5px;  top: 0; right: 0; max-width: 300px; z-index: 999;">
       <input type="text" id="search21" />
       <button type="button" id="submit_form"  >Cautare</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#submit_form').click(function(){
    var queryre = $('#search21').val();
                find(queryre);
                return true;
    })
</script>
```

**Update:**
The problem that I found is the with this code I try to simulate the CTRL+F and the first word is found in the input and become blocked there(

Comment: because you return from function

Comment: Also if I delete the "return" the same thing happen (

Comment: okay, what will happens when click button?

Comment: if I click the button the input value became blue, and nothing happens. But if I complete the input and just click one time in another place then  button and input,  then on button click the function is called

Comment: Your code works fine https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/157/

Comment: ok, but the problmes is in that you comment the find() function, but I need this, beacause it's used for searching in the page

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="submit" id="submit_form"  >Cautare</button>
```

change button tag to above code.
it will work.